# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key and supported architectures

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

What if I only include armv7 to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`? Will my app run on all after-armv7 archs? Or it will run only on armv7 devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only on armv7 devices.

> Include this key if your app is compiled only for the armv7
>   instruction set.

Please have look at the documentation of [Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) for more details.

Comment: Well, I had, just want to make sure. The question is will those binaries(compiled for armv7) run on arm64 devices, for example.

Comment: If you go through the document there are tables for everything you can check on that